# How to filter data of an object array with lodash

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

```
var brands = [];
brands = [null, {
  "id": "1",
  "image": "/images/brands/surf_excel.png",
  "name": "Surf Excel",
  "productCount": "6"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "image": "/images/brands/rin.png",
  "name": "Rin",
  "productCount": "5"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "image": "/images/brands/ariel.png",
  "name": "Ariel",
  "productCount": "4"
}];
```

Now i want to get the name where id  = 3. I tried

```
var data = _.filter(brands, { 'id': 3 });
console.log(data.name);
```

But its giving error can't read property of undefined. Assuing there will be only one record for id =3, Can anyne help me on this. How to get name from given id in the above structure.

If there is any better way to get the same result that is also appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have specified [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) and using it's `_.filter()` method. You can use pass predicate which can a function which will be invoke per iteration. As note it will return you an array.

```
var data = _.filter(brands, function(brand){
   return brand != null && brand.id == 3;
});
console.log(data[0].name);
```

if you want only one element the use [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs#find)

```
var data = _.find(brands, function(brand){
   return brand != null && brand.id == 3;
});
console.log(data.name);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use native JavaScript **[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method.

```js
var brands = [];
brands = [null, {
  "id": "1",
  "image": "/images/brands/surf_excel.png",
  "name": "Surf Excel",
  "productCount": "6"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "image": "/images/brands/rin.png",
  "name": "Rin",
  "productCount": "5"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "image": "/images/brands/ariel.png",
  "name": "Ariel",
  "productCount": "4"
}];

var data = brands.find(function(v) {
  return v && v.id == "3";
});

console.log(data.name);
```

Check [polyfill option for find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) for older browser.

---

If you want to filter out the array then use **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method.

```js
var brands = [];
brands = [null, {
  "id": "1",
  "image": "/images/brands/surf_excel.png",
  "name": "Surf Excel",
  "productCount": "6"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "image": "/images/brands/rin.png",
  "name": "Rin",
  "productCount": "5"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "image": "/images/brands/ariel.png",
  "name": "Ariel",
  "productCount": "4"
}];

var data = brands.filter(function(v) {
  return v && v.id == "3";
});

console.log(data[0].name);
```

---

**UPDATE :**
You are provided an object as the second argument as per documentation which uses [`_.matches`](https://lodash.com/docs#matches) for property value comparison. In your array `id` property holds a string value but you were provided  as a number in the filter  just change it to string will make it work or use callback function as in @Satpal answer.

```js
var brands = [];
brands = [null, {
  "id": "1",
  "image": "/images/brands/surf_excel.png",
  "name": "Surf Excel",
  "productCount": "6"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "image": "/images/brands/rin.png",
  "name": "Rin",
  "productCount": "5"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "image": "/images/brands/ariel.png",
  "name": "Ariel",
  "productCount": "4"
}];
var data = _.filter(brands, {
  'id': "3"
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: IMO, If OP is asking about `filter`, there must be possibility of multiple elements having asked `id`

Comment: @Rayon :  then he wouldn't use `data.name` :)

Comment: @Rayon :  anyway I just added filter method also :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using `filter()` instead of `find()`, you're actually pretty close. The reason you're not seeing any results is because the object predicates that you can pass to `find()`/`filter()` perform strict equality comparisons. Meaning, `3 === '3'` will evaluate to false.